# Problem space in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, space

In practice I have a button that sends the request to a URL to a UIWebView eg: tel:124324 4563, but unfortunately it does not load the page because there is a space. How do I remove the space? as happens in Mobile Safari that I replace it with %20?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is:

```
[string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

As documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding%3a).

Answer (score 2):

`- (NSString *)stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding`

You can use `[myString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`